# django - using urls in templates from variable in views

Tags: django, templates, url, view

Suppose I have this view

```
def foo_bar(request):

    context = {
        'url': 'app_name:foo"
    }

    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

And in the template, I want something like this:

```
<form action="{% url {{ url }} %}">
...
</form>
```

However, it throws `ID expected`

Is there a way to make this work?

Comment: That would not possibly show "ID expected". Please show the actual code you are using and the exact error message.

Comment: Don't use `{{ }}` inside a template tag. Use `{% url url %}` instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe a better way will be to use `django reverse`?

```
from django.urls import reverse

def foo_bar(request):

    context = {
        'url': reverse('app_name:foo'),
    }

    return render(request, 'template.html', context)
```

And in the template simply:

```
<form action="{{ url }}">
...
</form>
```